# CSS Code : important not working in earlier or latest position

Tags: html, css

Check the link i have inside this picture.

[image: Link Position under Div]

Whereas when I add this it changes the link color to blue. But, I wont touch the line 352 as it said (color white in css). So I add this my new code below:

```
.itemAuthorLatest a, .itemTagsBlock a, .itemAuthorLatest a:hover, .itemTagsBlock a:hover {
  color: #4051b !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I put it earlier (top of the css). And no effect. Then, I tried to put it in the latest (bottom of the css). Still seems no effect at all. Any clue?

Comment: Posting picture here will not help you buddy. Post your HTML as well.

Comment: need some more information here, does it work when you style it inline?

Comment: Are you sure about the element in your screenshot? In page, it is displayed as "database configuration", but in Elements dev tool, your highlighted `a` element should display "Membuat file..."

Comment: Seems to me like your links are white, you have 2 links before the one you highlighted in your list that are not visible. The one you highlighted might be visited or in focus so that overrides your color. Also you don't have to put classes "odd" and "even" on your li elements, you can do it via css like ul li:nth-child(even) { ... }, and ul li:nth-child(odd)

Answer (score 0):

This is same class and another file so when first was file loaded only affected. so you need scope class and ids and you are missed one color code of value,

```
div#k2Container .itemTagsBlock ul.itemTags li a{
    color: #4051bc !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```